# What was a "necromancer" to Tolkien?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In nodern fantasy fiction, everyone knows what a necromancer is: a dark wizard who traffics in magic dealing with death, and specifically *undeath,* calling up the dead as servants, frequently as soldiers.

But that's not what we see in the foundation of modern fantasy fiction.  In *The Hobbit,* a dark, shadowy figure called "the necromancer" is briefly mentioned as a reason not to take a certain route.  Later, in *The Lord of the Rings,* Gandalf identifies this necromancer as Sauron.

But Sauron is never seen raising armies of the undead.  There is in fact one point where an army of the dead is called up for military purposes, but it's *Aragorn* who does this, to fight against Sauron's forces!

It seems that "necromancer" meant something very different to Tolkien than the modern understanding of the word.  Do we have any insight from his extensive writings and notes explaining what "the necromancer" did to earn that title?

Comment: Your post ends in mid-word.

Comment: Remember that Tolkien was primarily a linguist (philologist). There is no possibility that he did not know exactly what "necromancer" meant.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes but who would have thought it possible that a philologist wouldn't know that the plural of "dwarf" is "dwarfs"?

Comment: @jwodder Gah!  No idea how that happened.  Fixed now.

Comment: @user14111 ITYM "dwerrow" :)

Comment: @user14111 I believe he covered that in one of the appendices. Used "dwarves" on purpose.

Comment: https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_236 for Tolkien complaining about the "correction" of "dwarves" by a publisher.

Comment: History of Middle-earth 6 has a bunch of stuff that makes it clear Tolkien was thinking about how to leverage the moniker (eg the Black Riders being, at one point, Barrow-wights...)